# How to structure a new ASP MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I need to start a new mvc project and as always I have issues about asp identity, never know where to put it!

I plan to organize solution like this:

- ProjectWebUI - mvc app with asp identity framework (made from internet template with authentication)
- ProjectDataAccessLayer - with repository classes that use `dapper` as database access technology
- ProjectWebAPI - web service

But I have a little confusion and before start coding I need advice from someone more experienced (as until now all my projects were just one project with data access in it):

1. Is it good idea to have asp identity inside WebUI project that use standard Entity Framework for data access and use dapper for other data access in separate assembly?
2. If asp identity is inside WebUI project will I have some issues to receive authenticated access to WebAPI project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I organized one of my recent projects:

- `Common` — this is a core project in the solution. It contains all the domain entities along with the `ApplicationUser` class that inherits from `IdentityUser` class from ASP.NET Identity Framework. Normally this class is found in a new ASP.NET MVC project template; I decided to put it into the core library because it represents a common entity that may be required for higher layers and levels of abstraction. Because of this, `Common` references `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` assemblies.
- `DataAccess` — this project references `Common` library and contains Entity Franework `DatabaseContext` as well as some repositories. I use Code First approach and my `DatabaseContext` is inherited from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. So it gives me a nice database structure with tables for `Users` and `Roles` and other ASP.NET Identity stuff as well as tables that represent my custom business entities from the `Common` project, so I can easily connect my custom entities with Identity objects.
- `WebApi` — this is a `REST` service that uses `DataAccess` and `Common` libraries. All the authorization and authentication job is done here using token authentication.
- `Web` — this is just a web client for my `REST` service.

So, to answer your question: you can keep your ASP.NET Identity classes and Entity Framework database context inside a single project if it is really small and easy to manage; otherwise, it would be better to step away from the default project template and introduce layers for each major application module.

Comment: So you didn't changed anything inside AccountController? I ask this because that controller talks directly to database and is there a real reason to move each data access from there to separate assembly (DAL)?

Comment: @1110 Yes, I changed `AccountController` to use `DatabaseContext` from the `DataAccess` project. If your project is not really tiny or if you want to implement other clients for your WebApi, you should definitely move data access logic from there into a separate assembly.

Comment: So that means that I should move login, register and all other user related fuctions out of accountcontroller to dal? Or just DbContext?

Comment: Move just `DbContext` to the data access layer. To implement register/login functionality in your `AccountController`, use `ApplicationUserManager` which (indirectly) depends on the `DbContext`.