# Asp.Net Identity, Web project and DAL Layer‏

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

Today I need some suggestion with one of the issue I am current struggling with

I am working on a project which has 3 layers

```
1) DAL
2) BAL
3) Web
4) Entities (This is a separate project which contain only the entities 
         that will be use to create DB tables with EF Code first)

Entities being reference in all the 3 layers
DAL being referenced in BAL and Web
BAL being referenced in Web
```

I want to get `DAL` reference out from `Web` project, my `Web` project usually talk with `BAL` all the time. The only reason I have to referenced `DAL` because of `ASP.NET Identity` `Startup.Auth.cs` and `IdentityConfig.cs` classes. Each of the file contain a single line of code that need an access to my `DBContext` which resides inside my `DAL` project.

**IdentityConfig.cs:**

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager
         (new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<MyDbContext>()));
```

**Startup.Auth.cs:**

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext(MyDbContext.Create);
```

How could I possible adjust things that I don't have to reference DAL inside Web project? Can you please suggest

Thanks

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345773/i-need-help-on-structuring-new-asp-mvc-app) useful. The main idea is to place your `ApplicationUser` class inside some common assembly (`Entities` in your case). The additional benefit of that refactoring is that you'll have a single `DbContext` for both domain and ASP.NET Identity entities. For more details on that topic, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807810/mvc5-identity-multiple-context-in-entityframework).

Comment: Unfortunately, my app structured little different than the suggested one. I don't think this work in my case until I change accordingly which I can't

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a 4 layer architecture. Implement the corresponding logic in Data Access Layer and reference it in Business Layer. So finally you can refer only BL in your Web.

Comment: Are you trying to say, I need to move those two classes `Startup.Auth.cs` and `IdentityConfig.cs` inside DAL?

Comment: If so, I don't think it would be a great idea to move those in DAL.

Comment: Do not move the class. Make sure they are in the same namespace where your DAL and BL lie.